# Remap capslock-key to modifier key ctrl+shift+alt with Autohotkey

Tags: windows, autohotkey, hotkeys

I'd like to use <kbd>Capslock</kbd> as a modifier key. To create this without risk of clashing with other key combinations, I'd like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>, i.e. <kbd>Capslock</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> would become <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>. <kbd>Capslock</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> would become <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>.

I would like to only configure the modifier key mapping in autohotkey, not each combination individually.

I've tried:

`Capslock::^!+`

and

`Capslock::Send ^+{Shift}`

But the first is recognized as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PlusSign</kbd> and the second doesn't seem to work at all.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$^CapsLock::CapsLock  ; Use Ctrl+CapsLock to toggle CapsLock

; Refer to http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/Remap.htm
CapsLock::
    SetKeyDelay -1
    Send {Blind}{Ctrl DownTemp}{Shift DownTemp}{Alt DownTemp}
return

CapsLock up::
    SetKeyDelay -1
    Send {Blind}{Ctrl Up}{Shift Up}{Alt Up}
return
```

Comment: Note to anyone that comes here before reading: http://superuser.com/questions/168380/how-to-remap-capslock-to-ctrlaltshift-in-autohotkey you must bind as `*CapsLock::` and `*CapsLock up::` to make it work